# Correct mock for Http/Controller context for a razor helper test unit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, razor, moq

I have an issue trying to create a unit test for testing a custom razor helper (that using the kendo grid razor helper).
The problems comes from the kendo grid helper, which try to access the following property : `HtmlHelper.ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider` (and throws a `NullReferenceException`. This exception comes from the access to the `ValueProvider` property of the controller context).

I concluded that my "mock" http/controller context is not correctly initialized. I try several solutions found on the internet for mocking the context, but I still have the problem).

This is my current unit test code:

```
ModelMock model = ...
ViewDataDictionary vd = new ViewDataDictionary(model);

var htmlHelper = CreateHtmlHelper<ModelMock>(vd);
string htmlResult = htmlHelper.PopinGrid(m => m.JsonList).ToHtmlString(); // This is the call of my helper.

... (asserts)
```

And my helpers for context mocking (they work with other simple unit tests for razor helpers):

```
public static HtmlHelper<T> CreateHtmlHelper<T>(ViewDataDictionary viewDataDictionary)
    where T : new()
{
    Mock<ControllerBase> controller = new Mock<ControllerBase>();

    Mock<ControllerContext> controllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>(
        new Mock<HttpContextBase>().Object,
        new RouteData(),
        controller.Object);

    Mock<ViewContext> viewContext = new Mock<ViewContext>(
        controllerContext.Object,
        new Mock<IView>().Object,
        viewDataDictionary,
        new TempDataDictionary(),
        new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

    Mock<IViewDataContainer> mockViewDataContainer = new Mock<IViewDataContainer>();

    bool unobtrusiveJavascriptEnabled = false;
    bool clientValidationEnabled = true;
    viewContext.SetupGet(c => c.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled).Returns(unobtrusiveJavascriptEnabled);
    viewContext.SetupGet(c => c.FormContext).Returns(new FormContext { FormId = "myForm" });
    viewContext.SetupGet(c => c.ClientValidationEnabled).Returns(clientValidationEnabled);
    viewContext.SetupGet(c => c.ViewData).Returns(viewDataDictionary);
    // I add the following line because the "Controller" property of the viewContext was null (strange, given that I initialize the view context with the controller context).
    viewContext.SetupGet(c => c.Controller).Returns(controller.Object); 

    mockViewDataContainer.Setup(v => v.ViewData).Returns(viewDataDictionary);
    HttpContext.Current = FakeHttpContext();
    return new HtmlHelper<T>(viewContext.Object, mockViewDataContainer.Object);
}

public static HttpContext FakeHttpContext()
{
    HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest(string.Empty, "http://mockurl/", string.Empty);
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
    HttpContext httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);

    HttpSessionStateContainer sessionContainer = new HttpSessionStateContainer(
        "id",
        new SessionStateItemCollection(),
        new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(),
        10,
        true,
        HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
        SessionStateMode.InProc,
        false);

    httpContext.Items["AspSession"] = typeof(HttpSessionState).GetConstructor(
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
            null,
            CallingConventions.Standard,
            new[] { typeof(HttpSessionStateContainer) },
            null)
        .Invoke(new object[] { sessionContainer });

    return httpContext;
}
```

Is anyone know the good solution for mocking a full http/controller context ?

Thanks !

Comment: What's the code you are trying to test?

Comment: It's a helper that enclose a kendo grid. The exception is thrown during the kendo grid initialization (external code). I decompile the Kendo DLL to find the reason of the problem and I found that a call to the ValueProvider property of the controller is done (in the ProcessDataSource method of the kendo grid), whereas calling this property (in the "watch" window) provokes the same exception. Thus the problem, besides the fact that the kendo grid helper is not working, is that the "ValueProvider" property is not accessible.